# Create a BTC account programmatically

Tags: blockchain

Is that possible to create new BTC(or any other cryptocurrency) account through free api or kind of?

Comment: What do you mean by "account"? In Bitcoin and exchanges you have private keys and public addresses. There are no accounts. Do you mean exchange account?

Comment: Hi pbies, yes, I mean account for exchanging.

Comment: exchange on the Internet = an exchange portal, not exchanging.

Comment: You can only create new BTC by mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is that possible to create new BTC [...] account through free api**

The Bitcoin network doesn't have accounts, it is a peer to peer network. To receive and send BTC you only need to install wallet software on your computer or phone. You don't need to create any account.

> **I need to create address, which could send and receive BTC from another addresses**

The normal way to do this would be to download some [wallet software](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) to your PC and use that to create addresses.

If you must do it using an API, you can choose wallet software that has an API. For example the *Bitcoin Core* application software has an API that includes

[`GetNewAddress`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getnewaddress.html)

> `getnewaddress ( "label" "address_type" )`
>
> Returns a new Bitcoin address for receiving payments.
>
> If ‘label’ is specified, it is added to the address book so payments received with the address will be associated with ‘label’.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create an address completely offline.
All addresses exist even if never used in a transaction.

Algorithms needed to generate a new BTC keypair:

```
 secp256k1
 sha256
 ripemd160
 base58
```

Comment: Hi CS, no, I need to create address, which could send and receive BTC from another addresses, doesnt matter which exactly.